# kotlin Constructor parameters are missing ？

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, android-glide

I wrote a MaskShapeTransformation for Glide, so I want to pass a drawable in my Transformation and draw this drawable with The original bitmap to make a mask effect.

In the beginning, I pass a drawable like this and with a SoftReference to avoid memoryleak.

```
class MaskShapeTransformation(drawable: Drawable): BitmapTransformation() {
       private val weakDrawable = SoftReference(drawable)
       .....
}
```

but when I get drawable with `weakDrawable.get()?` the drawable was null
[image]

I don't know why, but I tried everything until I change my Constructor, I just add `val` to modified drawable like this

```
class MaskShapeTransformation(val drawable: Drawable): BitmapTransformation() {
       private val weakDrawable = SoftReference(drawable)
       .....
}
```

Something amazing happened, the `weakDrawable.get()?` work well!
[image]

I am very confusing, Can anyone tell me why that is？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point: `WeakReference` will, roughly, keep a reference only so long as something else is also keeping the reference alive.

Second point: Kotlin constructor syntax means that these are *very* different:

- `MaskShapeTransformation(drawable: Drawable)`
- `MaskShapeTransformation(val drawable: Drawable)`

The first one just says that you must pass a `Drawable` to the constructor. The second one says that too, but *also* creates a field on the class and intializes it with the value passed. That means that the second form gives you an object that has two fields:

- `drawable`: holds the passed-in drawable
- `weakDrawable`: a weak reference wrapping `drawable`.

Put them together, and now you have a class that has a strong reference to the Drawable which means that the weak reference will also be kept alive.